# Finding replacement transistors

Tags: transistors

I'm trying to build a [buzzbox](http://www.dansmc.com/Buzz_Box.pdf) from old schematics from the 70s. The general idea is to re-purpose a (morse) code practice module. The module isn't sold anymore but I have the schematics:

[image: code pratice module schematic]

I've been able to [find](https://www.theprojectasylum.com/electronicsprojects/radioshacktransistors/radioshacktransistors.html) the specs for the transistors as follows:

| Number | Family | Diss., mW | VCBO V | VEBO V | Ic mA | Typ Hfe | Type | Case Style | Cat. No. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RS-2021 | Gen. Purpose Amp and Med. Power Switch | 350 | 12 | 4 | 80 | 30 | PNP | TO-92 | 276-2021 |
| RS-2031 | Gen. Purpose Audio Amp | 200 | 30 | 6 | 50 | 120 | NPN | TO-92 | 276-2031 |

I've also found a [website](https://alltransistors.com/crsearch.php) to help find transistors remplacements but :

- I don't have values for all fields
- I get a ton of results which I can't tell apart.

Can you help me ?

Comment: What's the typical battery voltage?

Comment: The article shows two AA battery cells (3V). The PNP output transistor saturates with 0.2V then the max current is 2.8V/8 ohms= 350mA. The max allowed current in a 2N4403 is 600mA so it will be fine.

Comment: It could be educational to build a test rig on perfboard or circuit board with sockets for the transistors, then try various ones.  Will find that some devices work better than others in this role.

Comment: The transistors don't do much that the switch does alone with a battery and series cap with a 1.5 or 9V battery That cct could be improved

Comment: I built the circuit with a BC546 and 2N2907. It didn't work unless I increased the value of the resistor at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any general purpose type will do e.g. 2N4401/2N4403.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try ordering that and see how it goes.